# Get count of one day, seven days and thirty days in MySQL

Tags: mysql, count

I'm wondering if it's possible to do a query like:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT `User`) FROM `test_table` WHERE `createdDate` >= now() - INTERVAL 1 DAY AS Day
&&
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT `User`) FROM `test_table` WHERE `createdDate` >= now() - INTERVAL 7 DAY AS Week
&&
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT `User`) FROM `test_table` WHERE `createdDate` >= now() - INTERVAL 30 DAY AS Month
```

The query would ideally return the amount of users that were created in the past month/week/day.

Comment: you want to get all users whom signed up in the past month/week/day ?

Comment: No, I'd just like to count the users that signed up in the past day/week/month

Comment: Like, 4 Users Today, 15 This week, 230 This Month

Comment: So why do you use `AND` between queries? why don't you take them as 3 separate queries?

Comment: Do your `test_Table` contain duplicate user records?

Comment: @SubrataDeyPappu No, doubt it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT 
IFNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN `createdDate` >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),'0') AS 'LastDay',
IFNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN `createdDate` >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 7 DAY THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),'0') AS 'LastSevenDays',
IFNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN `createdDate` >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 30 DAY THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),'0') AS 'LastThirtyDays'
FROM 
test_table
WHERE `createdDate` >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 30 DAY;
```

Comment: Please Check this query @FilipBusic

Comment: Works fine, but it doesn't return the date(s) of when the users were created.. For example, (Monday == 4 Users, Tuesday == 2 Users) etc.

Comment: Basically, I'm trying to put these values in a chart, so I need to get Daily/Weekly/Monthly + Dates of all these so I can easily display the data

Comment: You asked for summary of last day, last seven days and last thirty days created users. This particular query always returns one row having three columns (`last day` , `last seven days` and `last thirty days` created users count).

Answer (score 0):

Just use DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT `User`) as dailyUser FROM `test_table` WHERE `createdDate` >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)

SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT `User`) as weeklyUser FROM `test_table` WHERE `createdDate` >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK)

SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT `User`) as monthlyUser FROM `test_table` WHERE `createdDate` >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
```

Comment: This works great! Is it possible to include like: SELECT DATE(`createdDate `) Week to get the date(s) that users signed up?

Comment: Yes. Just: SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT `User`) as dailyUser, createdDate FROM `test_table` WHERE `createdDate` >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)

Comment: I mean something like this: SELECT DATE(`createdDate`) Month, COUNT(DISTINCT `User`) Count FROM `test_table`

Comment: Yeah but createdDate is already a datetime field or? or you wann just get the date without the time?